# Javascript Floating div that always ontop when scrolls down

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

What is the right way to build simple floating `div`s using Javascript (or CSS programmatically)
that is on top and always visible when scrolling down?

Now I've seen examples like [this](http://www.jtricks.com/javascript/navigation/floating.html). When you scroll down you see the div jumping and a delay. I want it to constantly be on top when the content of the page is not my ,
  the script will be injected via chrome extention

can it be done?
something like  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c47Qp/) ; but less complex and not depend on the page content

Comment: I believe there are lots of those things on google, couldn't you find it there?

Comment: I don't think you need javascript here : ) You need just `position: fixed`

Comment: yeah i found few but not what i need , i can't wrap the content of the page with div's for start , and most of the examples are using jQuery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `class` or `id` of the element you want to keep on top you should apply some CSS rules,

for example, if your element class is `.topnavigation`

you could do the following in jQuery

```
<style>
.topnavigation {
    width:;/* add the width here */
    position:static;
}
.topnavigation.scrolling {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
</style>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50) // change 50 to what you want (work out how far the nav is from the top of the page alraedy and add it there, that'll make it smoother transition)
    {
        $('.topnavigation').addClass('scrolling');
    } else {
        $('.topnavigation').removeClass('scrolling');
    }
});
</script>
```

If you can't use jQuery you could do the following with normal javascript:

**Updated: 06 Jan 2017**
I've updated this to use the document.querySelector and Element.classList methods. All modern browsers and IE 10 > support these methods.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',checkPosition,false);
function checkPosition()
{
    // #theid or #theclass or standard element selector
    var xNAV = document.querySelector("#topnav"); 
    if(window.scrollY > 50)
    {
        xNAV.classList.add("scrolling");
    } else {
        xNAV.classList.remove("scrolling");
    }
}
```

Comment: quick question just if you can give me hint , if i like to do it 
but now the div will be always at the bottom?

Comment: ohh ok, then you could change the css from `top:0px;` to `bottom:0px;`

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ, This adds the `scrolling` class multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, determine when you want it to be floating, then add css: `position:fixed`